# Can PC register point to a memory zone different from text segment?

Tags: process, operating-system, cpu-registers

I have two questions about PC register:

1. Can a CPU fall in the case of having its PC register point to a memory cell that is not in the process's text segment ? If so, is the process just terminated or the machine is dead ?
2. When the cpu executes a process, it keeps iterating over instructions by incrementing PC. Let's suppose that PC points to the last instruction. How does the CPU know that the process has finished so that it does not increment PC ?

For the second question, I think it can be done by looking at the number of frames in the stack. If we call a return on the last frame, then the process has normally finished. But is this what is done actually ?

Answer (score 1):

In case 1, when the program counter points to an invalid address, the processor raises an exception as the MMU will indicate a fault. The OS will then typically terminate the process, e.g. with SIGSEGV. You can try this easily from within C by executing `((void (*) (void)) (0xDEADBEEF)) ();` (substitute with any invalid address). It would be a huge security issue if such a simple memory fault could crash the machine!

If such an invalid access happens within kernel space, it depends whether the kernel has configured the location as inaccessible in the MMU. If yes, the CPU will again cause an exception, in response to which the kernel can e.g. print an error message. If no, the behaviour depends a lot on the CPU and the address involved; there might be some hard fault exception crashing the system or nothing happens at all.

Case 2 is never supposed to happen. When the `main()` function in C returns, the C runtime library executes the [`exit`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_(system_call)) syscall, after which the OS will terminate the process. If you code in assembly language, you have to call that syscall manually when the program should quit. Note that after the `main()` function, there may be other functions in memory, which of course should *not* be executed after `main()` returns. The last instruction in a program's text segment needs to be some kind of jump/return/call to some valid instruction; if it is an "ordinary" instruction like `add`, the CPU will then attempt to execute an invalid memory location after that, in which case 1 applies (program is terminated/crashes). Of course in C programs, all code is organized in functions, and each function ends with a return/jump instruction, so the last instruction in a C program's text segment *is* indeed a return/jump.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the answer on case 2, what if the assembly program does not call exit ?

Comment: Then the program will do something undefined; probably crash as the CPU attempts to execute a memory location outside the text segment, that hasn't been configured as existing and executable by the OS, which causes an exception.

Comment: For case 1, does it have to do with segmentation and that each segment has its access permissions ? If so, I suppose that the cpu maps each of its registers to the segments that they can point to (PC to text, SP to stack, ...) but I am not sure where this mapping is stored ?

Comment: It has to do with MMU pages. The OS allocates MMU pages for the program segments found in the executable file, and configures the MMU pages as readable/executable/writable as needed. To start a program, the OS sets the PC to the programs entry point (often called `_start`, defined in the file's header). It is then the program's responsibility to not set it to an invalid value (i.e. jump to an invalid address).

Comment: The SP is initialized to the stack top, but can in principle point anywhere, you could misuse it as an ordinary pointer. There is no check that the SP actually points into stack memory. However, function calls/returns access the SP, so if it doesn't point to an accessible location, calls/returns will crash the program.

Comment: If I have understood the first lines of your answer, you said there is a check by the cpu if PC points to an invalid address, but for the last two comments what I understand is that once PC or SP point to an invalid address, it is not the check of address that crashes the program, but the invalid content of the cells they point to ?

Comment: The PC, SP, ... registers are not checked for their contents. Only the memory accesses are checked. Since the PC is automatically accessed for every instruction, having the PC point to an invalid address will lead to an immediate crash. Having the SP point to an invalid address will only crash when you access the contained address. Memory cells can't contain invalid content, but the OS+MMU can forbid access to some locations, so the program is terminated if you attempt to access them; the actual access never happens, as the exception happens before.